# Select Group Information in MySQL, and Return Multiple Rows per Group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am using MySQL and I would like to include group averages in a selection, but it still display all rows.

Relevant Table: `Student(studentID, studentName, major, class, gpa)`

```
SELECT *, AVG(gpa) AS AvgClassGPA
FROM Student s1
WHERE gpa < (
    SELECT AVG(gpa) 
    FROM Student s2 
    WHERE s1.class = s2.class 
    GROUP BY class
)
GROUP BY NULL, class
ORDER BY studentID;
```

This returns only 4 rows (one for freshman, sophomore, junior and senior respectively). If I don't include both the AVG() select and the last GROUP BY class, I get the desired rows but without displaying the class averages. How can I get both?

Thank you to any who respond!

Comment: can you list down the columns you want as output? Your question is hard to understand

Comment: SELECT *, AVG(gpa) AS AvgClassGPA, so all of the Student columns, and the AVG(gpa)